# In "Primeval," Why Are Animals So Eager To Go Through Anomalies?

Tags: primeval

In the BBC series *Primeval*, the problems they encounter almost always stem from animals that come through anomalies.  In the next to last episode of Series 2, we see a girl's pet dog run through an anomaly.

I would think animals would be suspicious of something that seemed so different, so what is it about anomalies that almost guarantee that when one opens, animals will come through one?  And if it's so appealing, why is it when animals come through, they don't stick around the anomaly or go back through it?

Comment: If they are British animals, "Because They [the anomales] [are there](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2010/03/george-mallory-coins-because-its-there.html)!"

Comment: That's a good question, they do love to come through the anomalies! However, there are a lot of instances of creatures going back and forth through the anomalies; the show with the aquatic reptiles (can't remember their names) comes to mind, and others.

Answer (score 1):

Many animals are inherently curious.  A [study](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167487011000298) has been done specifically on dolphins, with results that indicate that at least dolphins seem to be affected by curiosity in a similar way to humans.  I imagine it's not a big leap to suggest that other animals are similarly affected.  Indeed, there is the well-known saying: ["Curiosity killed the cat"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/curiosity-killed-the-cat.html) which suggests that the trait has been observed in cats.

Anomalies are bright and they don't move fast, so probably appear to be non-threatening.  Annoyingly, I can't find evidence to back this theory on *apparent threat* up.  They also probably smell interesting (possibly smelling of whatever's on the other side?), but that's purely speculation.

I think it's reasonable to assume it's simply curiosity or a sense of discovery that leads animals to enter anomalies.  After all, humans are animals too and we're happy to do all sorts of [crazy things](http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/) in the name of exploration!